# How to test Kotlin/suspend function?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

hey guys I have tried this

```
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
internal class RecipeServiceImplTest {
@MockK
lateinit var apollo: ApolloClientConfig

@InjectMockKs
lateinit var recipeService: RecipeServiceImpl

@Test
fun getDietaryRestrictionsTest() {
    val requestConfig = RequestConfig(
        Optional.presentIfNotNull("en"),
        Optional.presentIfNotNull(1)
    )
    val stringList: List<String> = listOf<String>("ALCOHOL_FREE", "GLUTEN_FREE", "LACTOSE_FREE")
    val search: GetDietaryRestrictionQuery.Search = GetDietaryRestrictionQuery.Search(stringList)
    val data: GetDietaryRestrictionQuery.Data = GetDietaryRestrictionQuery.Data(search)

    coEvery {
        apollo.buildApolloClient().query(GetDietaryRestrictionQuery(requestConfig, 999))
            .execute().data
    } returns data
    
    var result: Any

    runBlocking {
        result = recipeService.getDietaryRestrictions("en", 1)!!
    }

    coVerify(exactly = 1) {
        apollo.buildApolloClient().query(GetDietaryRestrictionQuery(requestConfig, 999))
            .execute().data
    };
    assertEquals(data, result)


}
```

but it doesn't work saying

> class de.foodfittery.cms.generated.graphql.backend.GetDietaryRestrictionQuery$Data cannot be cast to class com.apollographql.apollo3.api.ApolloResponse (de.foodfittery.cms.generated.graphql.backend.GetDietaryRestrictionQuery$Data and com.apollographql.apollo3.api.ApolloResponse are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

my function is here

```
    override suspend fun getDietaryRestrictions(locale: String?, supportedApiVersion: Int?): GetDietaryRestrictionQuery.Data? {
    return this.apolloClientConfig.buildApolloClient()
        .query(GetDietaryRestrictionQuery(initRequestConfig(locale, supportedApiVersion),999))
        .execute().data
}
```

this is my config

```
 @Configuration
class ApolloClientConfig(private val appProperties: AppProperties) {
    @Bean
    fun buildApolloClient(): ApolloClient {
        return ApolloClient.Builder()
            .serverUrl(appProperties.foodfitteryCoreDevUri)
            .build()
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the argument of the method call in the `coEvery` block doesn't necesairly match the actual call argument. The call does not get mocked thus the error.

Try using `any()` instead of an actual value inside `coEvery` and `coVerify`:

```
coEvery {
    apollo.buildApolloClient().query(any())
        .execute().data
} returns data
```

Comment: hi it tried that ,but says this.  Not enough information to infer type variable D

Comment: no answer found for: ApolloClientConfig(#1).buildApolloClient()

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
cant find apollo client something like that